# K-means clustering Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

My problem is that it is difficult to get the optimal cluster number by using k-means, so I thought of using a hierarchical algorithm to find the optimal cluster number. After defining my ideal classification I want to use this classification to find the centroids with k-means, without iteration.

```
data= rand(300,5);
D = pdist(data);
Z = linkage(D,'ward');
T = cluster(Z,'maxclust',6);
```

Now I want to use the clusters defined in vector `T` and the positions in to k-means algorithm without iterations. Can anyone give a tip how to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the centroids given that you already clustered them in `T`, then you only need to compute the `mean` of `data` grouped according to `T`.